# Page not moving to the next page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to move to another page after register but it doesnt move to new page. it just saves data to data base and doesnt move. it remains on the same page. i need it to move to another page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_work/extra%20pages/screen/welcome.dart';
import 'LogIn.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'models.dart';

// had to switch the login part for sign up. So this page is Sign up.
class LogIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LogInState createState() => new _LogInState();
}

class _LogInState extends State<LogIn> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _user = User();

  TextStyle style =
      TextStyle(fontFamily: '', fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Center(
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/Artboardd.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                child: Builder(
                    builder: (context) => Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(

                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 15.0),

                              Text(
                        "Register",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                            fontSize: 50.0),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),

                              TextFormField(
                                obscureText: false,
                                style: style,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Email',
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.mail)),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Please enter your Email';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                onSaved: (val) =>
                                    setState(() => _user.email = val),
                              ),

                              SizedBox(height: 15.0),

                              TextFormField(
                                  obscureText: true,
                                  style: style,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Password',
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key)),
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 6) {
                                      return 'Password must be at least 6 characters';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  onSaved: (val) =>
                                      setState(() => _user.password = val)),
                              Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                 padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      onPressed: signup,
                                      child: Text('Register'))),
                            ])))))
      ],
    ));
  } 

  _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Registered Succesfully')));
  }
```

i cant tell if there is a problem with this code here. Can you please help

```
       void signup()async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      try {
        FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: _user.email, password: _user.password)) as FirebaseUser;
        user.sendEmailVerification();
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> SignUp()));
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.messgae);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is this method `user.sendEmailVerification();`? Where does it take you?

Comment: @PeterHaddad it was suppose to send the user an email to verify account but i havent written the code for it yet

Answer (score 0):

For me it works just using:

```
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Register(User: user,)));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i will check it out